# Click event on link using WebDriver shows "javascript:void(0)" on status bar

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mousehover

I am trying to click on first link from dropdown list which is generated on mouse hover event.

Tried with lots of options But NO success, it's Only seen "javascript:void(0)" on status bar. So far manage to displayed dropdown list on mouse hover. Only issue with click on first link.

```
<a title="Insert" href="#">
    <span>Insert</span>
</a>
<ul>
     <li class="standardContent">
         <a id="id193" title="Modules & Topics from a Library" href="#"> Modules & Topics  from a Library </a>
     </li>
      <li class="customModule">
```

Here I want to click on element "Modules & Topics  from a Library".  Since the id is dynamically changed. So can't use to make a click.

```
  Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement iconhover = driver.findElement(By.className("insertItems"));
        act.moveToElement(iconhover).click().build().perform();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        WebElement mod = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='standardContent']")));
        mod.click();
```

next try

```
  Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement iconhover = driver.findElement(By.className("insertItems"));
        act.moveToElement(iconhover).click().build().perform();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        WebElement mod = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='standardContent']")));
        WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='insertItems']/ul"));
        List <WebElement> ancartag= a.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        for (int i=0; i<ancartag.size();i++){
            System.out.println(ancartag.get(0));
            ancartag.get(0).click();
        }
```

Comment: Did you try chaining your actions together? `act.moveToElement(iconhover).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='standardContent']")).click().perform();`

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet below:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("Modules & Topics  from a Library"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: It didn't work.                                                         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("standardContent"));
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element)

Comment: can you try with WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("Modules & Topics  from a Library"));